# I need to populate a picker

Tags: ios, picker, pickerview

I'm new programming in Swift, and what I need is a pickerView (done programmatically) that is populated with Json Data. I succeeded populating the picker with the name of the object, but I need to select the name and catch the id of the object that came in the Json Data.

I would really appreciate answers with lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• First create an array to store fetched 'id's. Save id like done in  dataZoneName.

• Then on picker didSelectRow delegate pick the id corresponding to the selected string using row index

• Now idToken have the id for selected Name in picker.

• Also move alamofire data fetch code from viewdidLoad to a separate function. Also declare a parameter for id of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are using SwiftyJson from json parsing and Alamofire for hiting API.

when you hit API you can make a model using swiftyjson for example

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
struct UnitsModel {

var id: Int = 0
var name: String = ""

init(fromJson Json: JSON!) {
    
    if Json.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    
    id = Json["id"].intValue
    name = Json["name"].stringValue
}}
```

Now you need to map json response to your array and to do that you can use

```
fileprivate func APIRequestGetUnitsCompleted(response: Any?, error: Error?) {
    if let response = response{
        let json = JSON(response)
        
        let units = json["units"].arrayValue
        
        for index in 0..<units.count{
            let model = UnitsModel(fromJson: units[index])
            unitsArray.append(model)
        }
        
    }else{
        //print("Error")
    }
}
```

In your view controller make an array of type model which you just created and also create a variable to store ID

```
var unitsArray = [UnitsModel]()
var selectedUnitId = 0
```

Now you can use following code:

```
ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{


func createPickerView() {
    
    pickerView.delegate = self
    unitTextField.inputView = pickerView
    
}

func dismissPickerView() {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.action))
    toolBar.setItems([button], animated: true)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    unitTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

@objc func action() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    
    return unitsArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    
    return unitsArray[row].name
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    unitTextField.text = unitsArray[row].name
    selectedUnitId = unitsArray[row].id
    // selectedUnitId is variable in which id of selected option from picker view will be saved.

}}
```